# Mocking Input Facade in Laravel 4

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4

I am using this is a Form service.

```
$files = Input::file('my_file');
```

I'm trying to test it, but I can't seem to properly mock Input. The docs say not to mock the Request facade. There is no mention of the Input facade, even though they both point to the same class in the IOC container.

I've tried several methods, but they don't work. Any ideas?

```
    $mockInput = Mockery::mock('\Illuminate\Http\Request');
    $mockInput->shouldReceive('file')->andReturn($my_test_data);
    Input::swap($mockInput);
```

and

```
    Input::shouldReceive('file')->andReturn($my_test_data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, I was wrong. This does work. It does help to have it in the right test.

```
$mockInput = Mockery::mock('\Illuminate\Http\Request');
$mockInput->shouldReceive('file')->andReturn($my_test_data);
Input::swap($mockInput);
```

Also, I created an UploadedFile object and andReturned it:

```
$media = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile(
     $path,
     'orig_name_1.jpg'
);
$my_test_data = [0 => $media];
```

Comment: Does it still work? Laravel docs now say `Note: You should not mock the Request facade. Instead, pass the input you desire into the call method when running your test.`

Comment: That particular comment has been there for quite a bit. Generally speaking you shouldn't mock the Request facade. However, I couldn't find a way to test the file upload process.

Comment: Still using L4. Swapping doesn't work for me. However, what works is mocking the `all` method but mocking `get` don't.