# Laravel testing - Problems with created routes

Tags: unit-testing, testing, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a question about routing while testing packages. The function setRoutes creates new routes in the test file as follows:

```
class PackageTests extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase {
    protected function setRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'prefix' => Package::functionToCall1(),
            'before' => 'filter'
        ], function() {

            Route::get('/', function () {
                return "hello";
            });

        });
        Route::enableFilters();
    }
    protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->setRoutes();
        Config::set('app.url', "http://localhost/" );
    }
    public function testFunction1()
    {
        $crawler = $this->call(
            'GET', 
            'http://localhost/'
        );
        // doing this call, the function on the prefix is called
        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

Inside the function called in the prefix, functionToCall1() urls are not taken successfully. A call to `URL::current()` returns "/" and a call to `Request::fullUrl()` returns "http://:" when phpunit is executed but they returns the full url when used executing a url in the browser. This is the code of the package:

```
class Package
{
    function functionToCall1()
    {
        var_dump(URL::current() ); // returns "/"
        var_dump(Request::fullUrl()); // returns "http://:"
        // I want them to return 'http://localhost'
    }
}
```

I tried setting up the url `Config::set('app.url', "http://localhost/" );` but it was useless.

To sum up, is there a way to call a function in the prefix and get the testing url?

Thanks, I would really appreciate your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had to deal with a similar issue. 
My solution was found here:
[Mocking Laravel's Request::segment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941111/mocking-laravels-requestsegment-method)

Apparently there is an order of operations issue with testing a Request facade. 

I was trying to use Request::segments() before the request was being built, so there were never any segments to return. 

I imagine it's the same problem with `Request::fullUrl()`.

Here is my solution:

```php
class MyTestClass extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        // No call to parent::setUp()

        $this->app = $this->createApplication();
        $this->app->request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', '/some/uri');
        $this->client = $this->createClient();
        $this->app->boot();
    }

    public function testWhatever()
    {
        $this->call('GET', '/some/uri');
    }
}
```

This allows me to get the request data properly, even though it looks pretty bad.