# Skipping Lines of Code & Setting Variables inside Public Function within PHPUnit When Testing

Tags: function, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm sure something like this has been asked before, but I've read several forums and have not come to a solution.  I am using PHPUnit version 3.7.38, if that makes any difference.

I'm in PHPUnit testing a function.

```
    public function someFunction()
    {
        $variable2  = Input::get('someValue');

        if (strlen($variable2) == 0) {
            return Redirect::to('/somepage')->with(
                'notification',
                array(
                    'type' => 'danger',
                    'text' => 'text.'
                )
            );
        }

        ...More Code that needs to be tested
```

My problem is that everytime PHPUnit runs, $variable2 returns null because it can't get someValue.  The code the returns and skips the rest of the function.  I want to somehow skip over $variable2's declaration and assign it to a value that has a strlen() greater than zero, so the test covers the rest of the function.  Is there a way to do this?

I have read the documentation on PHPUnit's site about ignoring codeblocks, but have not had any luck with that.  Maybe I'm not implementing the

```
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
```

properly or maybe that's not even what codeCoverageIgnore is meant for.    I tried putting the @codeCoverage in the actual code I'm testing, but I don't think that would be right either seeing how I still want to test the if branch if it is true.  I wouldn't think you would have to edit the code being tested in order to test it either.

Answer (score 0):

```
@CodeCoverageIgnore
```

This is used to tell the code coverage calculations to skip the this section and not include it in the calculation of test coverage.  Therefore, this module would not be included in the counts for covered/uncovered lines of the test.

However, you really want to handle the Input:: method and set it. The best way to do this is to refactor your code, to move the Input rountine out, to be supplied by dependency injection, which would then allow you to Mock the Input routine to set your text string, and allow your test to continue.

```
class ToTest
{
    private $InputObject

    public function __construct($Input = NULL)
    {
        if(! is_null($Input) )
        {
            if($Input instanceof Input)         // The class that you were referencing Input::
            {
                $this->SetInput($Input);
            }
        }
    }

    public function SetInput(Input $Input)
    {
        $this->InputObject = $Input
    }

    public function someFunction()
    {
        $variable2  = $this->InputObject::get('someValue');

        if (strlen($variable2) == 0) {
            return Redirect::to('/somepage')->with(
                'notification',
                array(
                    'type' => 'danger',
                    'text' => 'text.'
                )
            );
        }

        ...More Code that needs to be tested
    }
}
```

Test:

```
class InputTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // Simple test for someFunctione to work Properly
    // Could also use dataProvider to send different returnValues, and then check with Asserts.
    public function testSomeFunction()
    {
        // Create a mock for the Your Input class,
        // only mock the someFunction() method.
        $MockInput = $this->getMock('YourInput', array('someFunction'));
        // Set up the expectation for the someFunction() method 
        $MockInput->expects($this->any())
                  ->method('get')
                  ->will($this->returnValue('Test String'));

        // Create Test Object - Pass our Mock as the Input
        $TestClass = new ToTest($MockInput);
        // Or
        // $TestClass = new ToTest();
        // $TestClass->SetInput($MockInput);

        // Test someFunction
        $this->assertEquals('Test String', $TestClass->someFunction());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm using Laravel 4 and tried to do that, but am unable to mock the Input class.  It returns Cannot redeclare Mockery_30_Illuminate_Support_Facades_Input::shouldReceive().   I have no idea why it is trying to redeclare shouldReceive,.

I saw another forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369584/mocking-input-facade-in-laravel-4 and tried \Illuminate\Http\Request, but that ended up in a nesting level of '100' reached error.

Comment: I do not use Laravel, but maybe post a more detailed question their forums, or even here on Stack Overflow, and you might get a direct answer.